# More like this - elastic search not giving proper results

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, morelikethis

Current data-

```
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 38.91894,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "evg_dev",
                "_type": "component",
                "_id": "907784",
                "_score": 38.91894,
                "_source": {
                    "component_type": "para",
                    "qual_data_desc": "test_text_136",
                    "last_changed_by": "testuserevg",
                    "document_used": "",
                    "element_detail": "<para><para>Tit fot&nbsp;tat&nbsp;tit</para></para><para/>",
                    "datetime_created": "2018-10-16T12:31:33.932Z",
                    "datetime_last_changed": "2018-10-16T13:13:15.372Z",
                    "created_by": "testuserevg"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "evg_dev",
                "_type": "component",
                "_id": "907783",
                "_score": 37.329224,
                "_source": {
                    "component_type": "para",
                    "qual_data_desc": "test_evg_213",
                    "last_changed_by": "testuserevg",
                    "document_used": "",
                    "element_detail": "<para><para>tit fot&nbsp;tat</para></para><para/>",
                    "datetime_created": "2018-10-15T14:39:15.696Z",
                    "datetime_last_changed": "2018-10-15T14:42:34.145Z",
                    "created_by": "testuserevg"
                }
            }
        ]
     }
```

Here is mapping for this-

```
"term_vector_analyzer": {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "word_delimiter",
                            "kstem", "english_stopwords"],
                "char_filter": ["html_strip"]
            }
"element_detail": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "kstem_words": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "term_vector_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

When we try to fetch result using more like this query, we don't get proper results.

Here is my more like this query-

```
{
"query":{
    "more_like_this": {
        "fields": ["element_detail"],
        "analyzer":"html_analyzer_without_tags",
        "like":"Tit fot tat tata",
        "min_term_freq":"1",
        "min_doc_freq":"1",
        "minimum_should_match":"10%"
    }
    }
}
```

And html_analyser_without_tag is -

```
"html_analyzer_without_tags": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "word_delimiter",
                                "kstem", "stemmed_appasense_stopwords_filter"],
                    "char_filter": ["no_escape_tag_char_filter"]
                }
```

We have also added terms like min_doc_freq and all but none of them works is there anything related to mapping setting which is why we are getting such error?

We have also tried to look if analyser results in proper values or not but it returns proper values,it tokenizes them returns each single word, even reducing the "minimum_should_match" to 1% didn't work for us.

Comment: May you elaborate on what you mean with "proper results", please? I mean, what do you expect as result?

Comment: I should get only 1 value where as I am getting multiple @B--rian